# Calculating sum with uneven rows from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

[image]

I tried This with adding 2 data tables in vb.net but it fails when group has 3rd level child (for e.g. if added 12, regular fees,5 in group table)  please tell me how i can i query database when child node creation is unlimited at group table

Currently trying call calc sub

```
Public sub calc
ds.fill("Select * From Group")
 for i =0 to ds.tables("group").count-1
 getheadamt(ds.tables("group").rows(i).item(0)
 next
end sub
Public Function GetHeadAmt(ByVal mcode As Integer)
    filldataset("select * from [Ledgers] where Undergroup=" & mcode, "gethead")
    Dim closbal As Double = getledgeramount(mcode)
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables("gethead").Rows.Count - 1
        closbal = closbal + getledgeramount(ds.Tables("gethead").Rows(i).Item(0))
    Next
    Return Math.Abs(closbal)
End Function
Function getledgeramount(ByVal mcode As Integer)
    Dim bal As Double = Trans(String.Format(select ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0)+ISNULL(SUM(opbal),0) from Transactions where ID='{0}'", mcode))
    Return bal
End Function
```

Comment: can you share your sql query

Comment: I think that you are using "Expanses" when you actually want "Expenses".  "Expanse" is derived from "expand" and an expanse is a large area, e.g. "the horse was allowed to roam over a large expanse of land".  An expense is something that costs something, thus it requires you to expend capital.